# ruby on rails form and passing its parameter to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, controller, parameter-passing

When the view pass the parameters to controller,
controller gets nil for all of the arguements somehow.

Can anyone how to fix this?? Thanks!

and I have no model called "Message"

controllers/messages_controller.rb

```
  def deliver

   recipient = User.find_by_username(params[:recipient])
   subject = params[:subject]
   body = params[:body]

   current_user.send_message(recipient, body, subject)
    redirect_to :controller => 'messages', :action => 'received' 
    flash[:notice] = "message sent!"

  end
```

views/messages/new.html.erb

```
<%=form_for :messages, url: url_for( :controller => :messages, :action => :deliver ) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :subject %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :subject %>
    </div> 

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :body %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :body %>
    </div> 

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your source HTML to better understand what FormHelpers do.

With the `form_for` `f.text_field` will generate names attributes in the format:

```
messages[subject]
```

Consequently, your params will be in the format:

```
params[:messages][:subject]
```

You can also use `<%= debug params %>` to inspect what's in params, it's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can get parameter value using 
`datas = params[:messages]`
These values are in array form. So you can fetch array `datas` If you want to individual data then use
`subject = datas[:subject]

body = datas[:body]`
To check run following code in view
`<%= subject %>`
this gives the value of subject.